# Azure AD Connect

Tags: azure, active-directory, azure-active-directory

Is there any way to use mvc3 application with azure AD connect. My application is mvc3 app and having some difficulties in installing some owin nuget packages. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Well as far as Nuget is concerned, you should explain what difficulties you are facing.
For Connecting an MVC3 web app with Azure AD there are plenty of articles available, you can follow this one for help https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh127794.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good sample and tutorial to integrate Azure AD within an existing MVC app:

- [Integrate Azure AD into a web application using OpenID Connect](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-openidconnect)